# Weirdness of matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am following [this](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#stacking-subplots-in-two-directions) tutorial to make two subplots horizontally. According to the examples, the following should work.

```py
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy

# Sample data
x = numpy.linspace(0, 2 * numpy.pi, 400)
y1 = numpy.sin(x ** 2)
y2 = numpy.cos(x ** 2)

figure, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axes[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axes[0, 1].plot(x, y)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-124cb6e8d977> in <module>
      8 
      9 figure, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
---> 10 axes[0, 0].plot(x, y)
     11 axes[0, 1].plot(x, y)

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

In addition, if I run `axes.shape`, I get the output as `(2,)`. I would expect it to be `(1, 2)`. What am I missing?

[Note that the earlier is a minimum working example which comes up as a special case in my code. I do not want to go via the `(ax1, ax2)` route in an earlier example because I do not exactly know how many subplots I want ahead of time, so I have to do this programmatically.

In particular, I have $ n $ features, and I want to subplots of shape $ (ceil(n / 2), 2) $. So I would use `axes[i // 2, i % 2]` where `i` is my iterating variable. But when $ n = 2 $, my code breaks down.]

Thanks in advance!

[Edit: added the context to answer Tim's comment.]

Comment: But your code is different from the example.  That was making a 2x2 array.  You're making a 1x2.  You just need `axes[0]` and `axes[1]`.

Comment: @TimRoberts  : I updated the question to add the context. I see that `axes[0]` and `axes[1]` works, but if I set up a 2D grid, it shouldn't behave like a 1D one even if there is just one dimension along which we move, no?

Comment: "Should" doesn't really matter.  I would have to call this a quirk.  It is what it is, and you need to work around it.  You can always `reshape` it; I think that's a numpy array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) for `plt.subplots`:

- if only one subplot is constructed (nrows=ncols=1), the resulting single Axes object is returned as a scalar.
- for Nx1 or 1xM subplots, the returned object is a 1D numpy object array of Axes objects.
- for NxM, subplots with N>1 and M>1 are returned as a 2D array.

This is the default behaviour, and it can be changed by setting `squeeze` argument to `False` (`plt.subplots(1, 2, squeeze = False)` in your case), in which case it will always return a 2D array:

> the returned Axes object is always a 2D array containing Axes
> instances, even if it ends up being 1x1.